# Can Here Developer API be used with Google Sheets to geocode?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, geocoding, here-api

I've been using a script on google sheets to get coordinates from addresses in a certain column that gets updated. Is there a way to use the Here API instead to get those coordinates? Googles limit is much less than here which is why I'm trying to switch.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can use [HERE Geocoding API].(https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-geocode-brief.html)

Here's what a call looks like using an API Key:

```
https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=5+Rue+Daunou%2C+75000+Paris%2C+France&apiKey=API_KEY
```